# Is this character a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

**Warning there are major spoilers in this question. Not all of them are hidden behind masked text blocks. Masking character name in title to avoid spoilers.**

I'm wondering whether

> Rey

was a Jedi youngling from

> Luke's new Jedi Order which was torn apart by Kylo Ren.

The reasons for my suspicion include:

Her flashbacks. She has flashbacks which include screaming. She was witness or part of a traumatic event. It also appears to me as if she was dropped off on Jakku at a young age. Presumably this would have occurred immediately following the fall.

She is about the right age to have begun training as a youngling under Luke's New Order from birth. Though Luke obviously trained people who were not newborns, I expect he would see the value in training newborns especially if Yoda's force ghost was still advising him.

After her memories are triggered by Kylo Ren during his mind probe, she displays mastery of the force at a technical level, rather than something raw and untrained. There are three obvious examples:

1. She reverses Ren's mindprobe and draws information from Ren, himself a powerful force user who has been using mindprobes for a long time.
2. She uses force persuasion on a stormtrooper. More than that, she knows what force persuasion is and persists in trying to use it even though she initially fails (because through experience she knows she can do it).
3. She overpowers Kylo's attempt to force-pull Luke's lightsaber, grabbing it herself.

The only information I remember to the contrary is that prior to the mindprobe she clearly did not remember either the force or being trained. I think this can easily be explained by her having a memory block placed on her for her own protection when she was essentially abandoned on Jakku. The block was then broken by Kylo's probe.

Does anyone remember any information from the movie which might contradict this notion or support it more definitively?

Comment: "Though Luke obviously trained people who were not newborns" Obviously? In Disney canon, we've met exactly one person who  we know was trained by Luke, and we have no idea when that person started training.

Comment: Jedi no, jedi youngling maybe.  The intro scrolling text says Luke is the last Jedi.

Comment: @William I put "jedi" in the title so as not to add spoilers to the title. Note that I state "jedi youngling" later in the question.

Comment: @phantom42 Leia states that they lost their son only after giving him up to Luke for training. I assumed this implied he was not a newborn.

Comment: @melchoir55 - Snoke was following him for a while, but not clear since what age he started actively influencing him.

Comment: @melchoir55 I would put jedi youngling in the title but you are welcome to do it however you would like.

Answer (score 4):

The best information against this theory I can think of *(and the really isn't a lot of canon info for or against it, in my opinion deliberately by Disney to create suspense and avoid spoiling surprises for next 2 films)*, is the ages.

We know that Kylo "teenage whiney Anakin wannabe" Ren is ~30YO, while Rey is 19 (I provided sources in earlier answer on the site).

Rey was abandoned on Jakku when she was about 5 (based on her looks in Luke's-lightsaber-induced Force Vision), meaning Kylo was ~15 at the time.

I seriously doubt that a 15 year old, even a grandson of Anakin, would be able to wipe out entire Jedi Academy of Luke's. Even Anakin was well over 20 in Revenge of the Sith.

But none of the canon sources I am aware of offer any details to be certain.

Comment: This begs another question, where was Luke when his order was being wiped out by a half trained teenager?

Comment: @Mayshar - "Listen, alll'y'all, we're all out of Corellian Beer! I'll just swing around the corner to pick more up!". Seriously, this is intentionally left unstated as it's almost obviously will be a major plot point revealed in Episodes 8 or 9

Comment: Maybe Rey's memory of being abandoned at 5 is implanted?

Comment: @shim - that wasn't a memory. It was a Force-vision from touching Luke's lightsaber.

Comment: Are you arguing semantics or are you suggesting it's not her in the vision?

Comment: @shim - I'm suggesting that a memory can be implanted, but a Force-vision comes from a Force itself and therefore cannot be "implanted" in the past (it can possibly be a false vision **currently** sent to you by another Force user, ala HarryPotter5 seing Sirius in trouble; but we know this one likely wasn't as it originated from Luke's lightsaber)

Comment: @Mayshar maybe that question points in the direction the Kylo subverted a number of the other students to become Knights of Ren, they then slaughtered those that wouldn't turn and Luke either couldn't fight them all, or couldn't bring himself to kill a number of teenagers that he would have felt close to and one of whom he was related to, i mean he wouldnt kill his father and his father did far more evil than Kylo/Ben had to that point

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn -  Evil will always win.... because Good. Is. Dumb. :)

Answer (score 3):

**No.** In *Rise of Skywalker* we learn that Rey was in fact Chancellor Palpatine's granddaughter. Her father was living on a Sith planet named Exegol. He escaped, fathered Rey and was subsequently tracked down (and killed) by a Sith loyalist named Ochi.

For the record, there's also no indication that Rey had any formal training in the use of the Force, either from her parents or from Luke's New Order, until she began training with Luke in *The Last Jedi*