# When did Kylo Ren turn to the dark side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

More specific question:

> Han and Leia "returned" to what they do best as a coping mechanism for their son (Ben is his name, I believe?) turning to the dark side and starting the New Jedi Massacre. Han back to being a smuggler, Leia back to being a politician-general-freedom-fighter-leader.

Relative to the founding of the Resistance, did that happen before or after?

Comment: He's still working on it, apparently.

Comment: I suggest looking at [this theory and it's answers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111785/is-this-character-a-jedi/120810#120810). There DVK-in-exile also answered the question which matches his answer here.

Comment: Look , I am not supposed to tell anyone this, but it was when I was in high-school. I was dating this real evil chick and she was heavily into S&M (That is where I got my helmet from). Anyway, it was around that time when she kept on stepping on my lightsaber.

Answer (score 4):

It's not known just how long has passed, and based on below, looks like won't be known till more canon is released.

But Pablo Hidalgo in a tweet indicated that it was probably less than 14-15 years, because Academy Attack (which was, *presumably*, soon after Ren's Dark Side turn) was less than that.

https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/679406636704776192?ref_src=twsrc^tfw

> *Alberto Sanz ?@Skysawyer 22 Dec 2015*
>   @pablohidalgo Do we know when the Academy attack happened in the timeline?   **14-15 before TFA perhaps**?
>
> *Pablo Hidalgo*
>   @Skysawyer Let's not call it a 'Jedi Academy.' But **it wasn't that long ago**. Timeline will be told through stories, not tweets. :)

AND

https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/679440221725851649?ref_src=twsrc^tfw

> *Audrey ?@natallianovna 22 Dec 2015*
>   @pablohidalgo wait just to clarify, do you mean that **it was more recent than 14/15 years ago?**
>
> *Pablo Hidalgo*
>   @natallianovna **Yeah. It was more recent than that**.

---

Additional *probable* evidence: Rey is 19 in TFA, and sees herself in flashback as a ~5YO being abandoned. Again, making squishy assumptions, if she was abandoned around the time Ben turned, that looks like ~14-15 years ago. Definitely far from firm or conclusive.

---

However, take that with a grain of salt - he COULD have turned earlier and hid it. Or turned, left the Academy, spent time training with Snoke, THEN came back and killed everyone. We simply don't know.

---

Usual disclamer: Hidalgo's twitter account, as usual, has a disclaimer "Don't cite tweets as canon." - and reinforces the reluctance to discuss THIS fact with "Timeline will be told through stories, not tweets". Caveat Emptor.

Comment: So I guess the best we can glean from this is that it's most probably discussed in planned-but-as-yet-unreleased lore?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - THAT, we can definitely assume to be true

Comment: Also, we don't have a first clue when Resistance was started, as of yet :(